# Make struct init() parameter accept two types?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I believe this would be generics but I am unsure of how to implement it. I have a simple struct for defining a button on my app. I want to be able to either pass directly in an `Image()` or compose an image with `Image(systemName: String)` if a user passes in a `String`.

```
import SwiftUI

public struct TextFieldStepperButton {
    let image: Image
    let color: Color
   
    // image: Image should accept both (String && Image)
    public init(image: Image, color: Color = Color.accentColor) {
        // Detect if image == String || Image then define it depending on result
        self.image = image
        self.color = color
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a problem of generics; you just need two inits.

```
public init(image: Image, color: Color = Color.accentColor) {
    self.image = image
    self.color = color
}

// And then add a convenience that calls the other:

public init(imageNamed: String, color: Color = Color.accentColor) {
    self.init(image: Image(systemName: imageNamed), color: color)
}
```

I would recommend having different parameter names (`image` vs `imageNamed`), but you could unify them and use `image` for both if you like.

Answer (score 0):

This does not require generics. Instead, traditionally, if you want this behavior you would simply create 2 different inits, one with a String parameter and one with an Image parameter. Once could be a 'convenience initializer' which handles the different input but simply calls the other init (minimize copied code). Like so:

```
public init(image: Image, color: Color = Color.accentColor) {
    self.image = image
    self.color = color
}


public init(imageNamed: String, color: Color = Color.accentColor) {
    self.init(image: Image(systemName: imageNamed), color: color)
}
```

If you really wanted only initializer for whatever reason, you could make the parameter of type Any, then type check that it is either a String or Image, handle that accordingly, and reject if it is neither.